# python json keep object order on output

Tags: python, json

```
class MessageCreator:

    def serialize(self,obj):
        return json.dumps(obj,sort_keys=False,indent=None, separators=(',', ':'))

    def createGroup(self,name,description,masterkey):
        return self.serialize({
                               'typ':str(types.CREATE_GROUP),
                               'group':[{
                                        'name':str(name),
                                        'descr':str(description),
                                        'mk':str(masterkey)
                                        }]
                            })
```

will return

```
{"group":[{"mk":"test","name":"test","descr":"test"}],"typ":"517"}
```

however i want the order to be kept intact like

```
{"typ":"517","group":[{"name":"test","descr":"test","mk":"test"}]}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Python dictionaries *nor* JSON objects have a defined order. They are **always** ordered arbitrarily. Why do you *have* to have a fixed order, what is your use case?

Comment: i specify a fixed order in a specification in order to compute signatures of payloads.

Comment: Then set `sort_keys=True` to ensure a stable key order. It doesn't matter to the consumer of this JSON what the order is, because they are allowed to use any order they like for the keys too.

Comment: or make your signature computer smarter about key ordering. Don't try to bend the JSON standard around this use-case.

Comment: @Martijn JSON encoder _keeps_ order of keys by default. The problem is only in `dict` which doesn't do that.

Comment: If you request key order to sign a payload there's a 99.99% chance you're doing signing wrong. Look at signing using HMAC: http://docs.python.org/2/library/hmac.html

Comment: @Tupteq: the JSON **standard** states that JSON objects use arbitrary order. The fact that the encoder just loops over dictionary items when encoding is merely a implementation detail.

Comment: i dont see how a HMAC is avoiding my problem: I want to generate a payload that is signed later on, I want to assure that a certain key order is kept, which is obvoiusly not the alphabetical used by sort keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), not a normal `dict`, because `dict` doesn't preserve order.

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

a = {'c':3, 'a':1, 'b':2}
print(json.dumps(a)) # Random order: a,c,b for example
a = OrderedDict([('c', 3), ('a', 1), ('b', 2)])
print(json.dumps(a))  # Desired order: c,a,b
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want order, use a list(`[]`). If you want random access, use a table(`{}`). You can keep a list of keys in order as a separate attribute and then resort by that after you read out the data.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `OrderedDict` instead of a normal dict.

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

print json.dumps(OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
import collections
data = (("typ","517"),
    ("group",[{"mk":"test","name":"test","descr":"test"}]))
od = collections.OrderedDict(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

change serialize() as follow

```
from collections import OrderedDict
order=["typ", "group"]
def serialize(obj):
    temp_list=OrderedDict()
    for each_order in order:
        temp_list[each_order]=obj[each_order]
    return json.dumps(temp_list)
```

Comment: the order is also required for subdicts

Answer (score 0):

As of Python 3.7, dictionaries will retain its order. From [Python 3.7 Changelog](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html)

> the insertion-order preservation nature of dict objects has been declared to be an official part of the Python language spec.